# Solve the ODE using taylor series: Finding recurrence relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series, taylor-expansion

Solve the following ODE using the series method:
$$(1-t)\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+x=0\quad x(0)=x_0,\quad\frac{dx}{dt}(0)=0$$
We guess that the solution takes the form
\begin{align*}
x(t)&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nt^n\\
\frac{dx}{dt}&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}na_nt^{n-1}\\
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}&=\sum^\infty_{n=2}n(n-1)a_nt^{n-2}
\end{align*}
Then we plug these into the original ODE to get
\begin{align*}
&(1-t)\sum^\infty_{n=2}n(n-1)a_nt^{n-2}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nt^n=0\\
&(1-t)\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}t^n+\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nt^n=0\\
&\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}t^n-\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}t^{n+1}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nt^n=0\\
&2a_2+a_0+\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left[(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+a_n-(n+1)(n)a_{n+1}\right]t^n
\end{align*}
We now need to set all the coefficients equal to zero.
$$2a_2+a_0\quad\text{for }n=0$$
$$(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+a_n-(n+1)(n)a_{n+1}\quad\text{for }n=1,2,3,...$$
Now I want to plug in values of $n=0,1,2,3$ to find a recurrence relation.
\begin{align*}
&n=0\implies a_0=-2a_2\\
&n=1\implies a_1=2a_2-6a_3\\
&n=2\implies a_2=6a_3-12a_4\\
&n=3\implies a_3=12a_4-20a_5
\end{align*}

This is the part that I am stuck with. I can definitely see a pattern but I am not sure how to write it out as a recurrence relation. Then once I have that, I am not so sure how to find the general solution.

Comment: $x'(0)=0$, so $a_1=0$. And it is order 2, so you have to give another initial value.

Comment: You know that $a_0=x_0$ and $a_1=0$, and you found that $a_2=-a_0/2$, $a_3=(2a_2-a_1)/6$, $a_4=(6a_3-a_2)/12$, etc. In general, $a_{n+2}=\frac{n}{n+2}a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}a_n$. Calculate a few terms like this, maybe you'll see a pattern and can prove it by induction.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein. This is far to be simple (even knowing the solution of the problem)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You’re right, this is not simple.

Comment: Factoring out $-x_0$, it looks like the exponential generating function of the sequence obtained by prepending $-1$ to [A058797](http://oeis.org/A058797).

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein. For sure, it is ... knowing the solution of the ODE

Comment: I found answer [here](https://12000.org/tmp/02182022/foo.pdf)  with the recursive relation.

Comment: @Nasser Wow. That is a very complicated solution. Thanks for the resource